# How do I apply KMP algorithm to string problems like http://www.spoj.com/problems/PERIOD/?

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, substring, computer-science

I have learnt KMP algorithm but have failed to implement it in string problems.
Can anyone suggest me how  to do the above problem in SPOJ using KMP algorithm?
link : http://www.spoj.com/problems/PERIOD/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume that prefix function for a prefix with length `i` is `p[i]`.
If `i mod (i - p[i]) == 0` then `K = i / (i - p[i])` else `K = 1`(the idea of the proof is that any period is a multiply of the smallest period and the smallest period is exactly `i - p[i]`).
So you can use KMP algorithm to compute prefix function for all prefixes of the string and then use the formula above.